# Copy/clone UIView in swift in 2021?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, copy, clone

There some similar questions but the answers use deprecated methods.

My solution which is similar to them but with modern methods:

```
func copyObject<T: UIView>() throws -> T? {
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:self, requiringSecureCoding:false)
        return try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? T
    }
```

The problem is it doesn't work fully (and it seems the other questions-answers have the same problem) - one of subviews has corner radius which is not copied. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Since this question goes back 10-years... and Archive/Unarchive does *quite* work... and Apple has not, in 10-years, implemented `copy` / `copyWithZone` on `UIView`... one suspects it has significant inherent issues. A question might be: What are you doing that you feel "cloning" a view would be a better approach than subclassing it?

Comment: @DonMag how subclassing will help me if I need for example to fulfill the stackview with a duplicates of the same view? Of course instead of duplicating I can place UIView init into a separate xib/storyboard or create a separate init method. But in the similar questions they provide a solution (even if it not fully workable)

Comment: *"... for example to fulfill the stackview with a duplicates of the same view ..."* -- if you wanted to fill a stack view with 10 Labels, would you create **one**  `UILabel` and try to `copy` it? Or would you create 10 labels?

Comment: @DonMag in my case I need to copy a horizontal stack view (label and 2 inherited views) inside to fulfill a vertical stack view. Note its formatting (font, colors and etc.) is partially declared inside xib. Why can't I clone it instead of recreating to reduce the count of xibs and/or xib root views?

Comment: Well, first... if you have a xib already, you can load it multiple times for multiple instances, so with that description there would be no need to "clone" it. Second, you don't need **any** xibs... a custom `UIView` can be created purely with code. Perhaps if you show a concrete example of what you're trying to do we could show you a good approach.

Comment: @DonMag I want to do something like declaring cells directly in storyboard. But in my case it is stack view inside table cell which is already reusable by itself

Comment: That sounds like a typical implementation... tableViewCell prototype, which includes a stack view that gets a varying number of arranged subviews (or other variable arrangement). Without an actual **example that demonstrates the need for a "clone" feature**, I still don't see why subclassing your view(s) wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would depend on instances what your `UIView` contains. For instance, let's say you want to clone a default `UILabel`. In 2024 (I'm playing Xcode 15.3 as of writing), you have to define some classes in  `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses:from:)` when unarchiving. The following code should work at least.

```swift
func clone(label: UILabel) throws -> UILabel? {
  let archive = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: label, requiringSecureCoding: false)
  // Define 3 classes here for UILabel, otherwise it throws an error
  return try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [UILabel.self, UIColor.self, UIFont.self], from: archive) as? UILabel
}
```

I got that by typical `lldb` debugging and I'm not sure if we could find a generic method to clone `any UIView` eventually.

Hope this helps.